# Is it possible to recover past metadata history for an MP3 File?

Tags: mp3, metadata, file-history

Currently trying to figure out and see if it's possible to pull up all previous metadata information on an MP3 to see where it was like downloaded from & what did the file look like before editing it

Comment: Do you have a backup? Both Windows and Mac *might* have a file history function turned on that can give you the file before your edited it.

Comment: I have it's original file

Comment: Then I maybe misunderstand the question. If you have the original file, why can't you look at the metadata of that original file? Isn't that the "past metadata" you're interested in?

Comment: Yes I'm asking on how can i pull that up

Comment: So you want to see the metadata of the original file, which you have? What metadata are you interested in? Artist? Album? And what do you mean then by "what did the file look like before editing it"?

Comment: Like the original artwork, artist name, album, genre and so on

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far? Have you tried any tools that can show metadata with the original file? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet and wanting to find out what i could use

Comment: Oh sorry, it's expected that you perform *some* research before asking: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask This prevents that someone will suggest something that you've tried already and which didn't work. Please do some minimal research and [edit] your question if it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to see previous metadata for an MP3 file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1733062/is-it-possible-to-see-previous-metadata-for-an-mp3-file)

Answer (score 4):

That isn't possible. Once metadata is overwritten or removed from a file it's lost.